# How to read *ngFor data into the component

Tags: angular

I want to read *ngFor data into the component. 
I am using pipes into *ngFor(*cdkVirtualFor) and I can not include this pipes into component. 
Also, array are complex and I need simply read *ngFor array from template to component.
My code:

```
<div
    *cdkVirtualFor="let item of (items | pipeOne : pipeOneData | pipeTwo : pipeTwoData1 : pipeTwoData2 | pipethree | pipefour)"> 
</div>
```

I need this data into the component (.ts) file.

Thank you in addition

Comment: The question is how can you apply pipe on the component side instead of template side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import all your pipes in component and apply pipe in component -

```
import { pipeOne } from './pipeone.pipe';

const transformedItems = new pipeOne().transform(this.items);
```

Comment: "I can not include this pipes"

Comment: if pipes are not custom still you can import like this - `import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`

Comment: Yes, you are write with this way, I have not problem to import pipes